# Save related models using Prisma

Tags: nested, nestjs, prisma, prisma2

I have two models, Quiz and QuizQuestions a One to Many relation, i recive both on the request and want to save them at once since they are related to each other. But i'm receiving Error on create

schema:

```
   model Quiz {
        quiz_id          Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
        quiz_description String          @db.VarChar(200)
        quiz_status      Int?            @default(1) @db.Integer
        questions        QuizQuestions[]

        @@map("quiz")
    }

    model QuizQuestions {
        question_id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
        id_quiz              Int     @db.Integer
        question_description String  @db.VarChar(250)
        question_type        Int     @db.Integer
        question_required    Boolean @db.Boolean
        quiz                 Quiz    @relation(fields: [id_quiz], references: [quiz_id])

        @@map("questions")
    }
```

try to create -->

controller:

```
@Post()
    public async saveNewQuiz(
        @Body() quiz: Prisma.QuizCreateInput
    ) {
        const result = await this.quizServiceDB.saveNewQuiz(quiz);
        return ResponseRest.buildSuccess(result);
    }
```

QuizCreateInput type auto generated by Prisma:

```
  export type QuizCreateInput = {
    quiz_description: string
    quiz_status?:     number | null
    questions?:       QuizQuestionsCreateNestedManyWithoutQuizInput
  }
```

service:

```
        public async saveNewQuiz(quiz: Prisma.QuizCreateInput) {
        const quizRepository = this.prisma.quiz;

        const quizSaved = await quizRepository.create({ data: quiz });

        return { quiz_id: quizSaved.quiz_id };
        }
```

---

Error given:

```
Invalid `prisma.quiz.create()` invocation: { data: { quiz_description: 'test', questions: [ { question_description: 'test', question_type: 2, question_required: false } ] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ } } Argument questions: Got invalid value [ { question_description: 'test', question_type: 2, question_required: false } ] on prisma.createOneQuiz. 

Provided List, expected QuizQuestionsCreateNestedManyWithoutQuestionInput: type QuizQuestionsCreateNestedManyWithoutQuizInput { create?: 
QuizQuestionsCreateWithoutQuizInput | List | 
QuizQuestionsUncheckedCreateWithoutQuizInput | List connectOrCreate?: QuizQuestionsCreateOrConnectWithoutQuizInput | List createMany?: QuizQuestionsCreateManyQuizInputEnvelope connect?: 
QuizQuestionsWhereUniqueInput | List }
```

Comment: Are you using a relational or non-relational database? Also, it seems like you're passing the body of the request directly into Prisma. Usually, you have to change the structure of the data from the controller layer to get it working with the data access layer.

Comment: I'm using postgreSQL, a relational database, i didn't understand what you meant by changing the structure of the data from the controller, can you give me an exemple?

Comment: @Blamet I think that you are missing a property in your data. It should look like this: { data: { quiz_description: 'test', questions:  { createMany: [ { question_description: 'test', question_type: 2, question_required: false } ] } } }. Note the "createMany" property before the list of questions